# revtex4-2 document class misaligns algpseudocodex right margin

Tags: margins, revtex, algorithmicx, algorithmic, algpseudocode

When using the `revtex4-2` document class with the `twocolumn` option,
the `algorithmic` environment of the `algpseudocodex` package
has a right margin which extends too far.
How do I fix this
so the right margin aligns with that of body text?
MWE below.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,nobalancelastpage]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}

\begin{document}
See the following lines of code.
The right margin seems to go further than that of body text.
See the following lines of code.
The right margin seems to go further than that of body text.

\begin{algorithmic}
    \State A long first statement to demonstrate where statements linewrap.
    \State A short second statement.
    \Comment{Short comment.}
    \LComment{Long comment.}
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

The `nobalancelastpage` class option is there
just so I can compare the margins of
the body text and the `algorithmic` environment.
Screenshot of MWE output below.

[image: Output of MWE.]

The problem goes away if I change one of the following:

- `revtex4-2` to `article`
- `twocolumn` to `onecolumn`
- `algpseudocodex` to `algpseudocode` (and delete `\LComment{Long comment.}`)

Comment: As a dirty hack, you could warp `\noindent\begin{minipage}{.96\linewidth}
...
\end{minipage}` around the algorithm

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, this works even _inside_ an `algorithm` environment (which usually wraps around the `algorithmic` environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty hack: use a minipage around the algorithm to make the line shorter:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,nobalancelastpage]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}

\begin{document}
See the following lines of code.
The right margin seems to go further than that of body text.
See the following lines of code.
The right margin seems to go further than that of body text.

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \State A long first statement to demonstrate where statements linewrap.
    \State A short second statement.
    \Comment{Short comment.}
    \LComment{Long comment.}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]